# Как запускать потоки или Runnable строго поочередно в Java?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Как сделать так, чтобы потоки выполнялись поочередно, то есть следующий поток не начинался раньше завершения предыдущего?

*Примечание: вызываю метод, который в отдельном потоке скачивает файлы из интернета.*

```
for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    downloadFile(metadata.getDriveId().encodeToString(), metadata.getTitle());
}

public void downloadFile(String id, final String name) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // скачивание
        }
    }.start(); 
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`Thread.join()` заставляет текущий поток ждать завершения другого. При этом работа текущего потока будет остановлена и это равнозначно тому, чтобы просто запускать все задачи в одном потоке.

Если вам нужно `N` потоков запускать поочередно и не ждать их в основном потоке (из которого запускаете), посмотрите на [java.util.concurrent.Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--)()

Этот метод выдает вам [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), способный принимать (submit) любое количество задач (Runnable) и последовательно по одной их выполнять.

Вы также можете отдавать не Runnable, a [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html). Тогда sumbit возвращает [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), который может вам пригодиться, чтобы получить какие-то данные о скачанном файле.

Answer (score 12):

Есть такой метод называется `Thread.join()` - позволяет дождаться завершения потока или запустить поток после некоторого ожидания.

За примерами [втыкаем сюда](http://www.journaldev.com/1024/java-thread-join-example-with-explanation)

Answer (score 8):

Вот, что говорит гугл в описании класса `AsyncTask`:

> Order of execution.
>
> Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

Начиная с API 11 запуск потока через `AsyncTask.execute()` ставит все следующие потоки после первого в очередь и они дожидаются окончания выполнения предыдущих , то есть задачи выполняются последовательно , а не параллельно.

Для верности можно использовать параметр [SERIAL_EXECUTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR), в вызове экзекутора

```
asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
```

который принудительно переводит `AsyncTask` в режим последовательного выполнения потоков.

Comment: _tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors_ А заставить программистов выучить смысл многопоточности не вариант? (Это я на гугл, а не на ваш ответ.) фейспалм.джпг

Comment: @VladD ключ `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` запускает "истинную многозадачность" для тех, кто в теме. Дело в том, что с самого начала в android была "двухзадачность", потом  они попытались по умолчанию запускать потоки паралельно в android 2.1-2.3 и столкнулись с кучей проблем "горе-программистов",   поэтому с android 3.0 вернулись к двухпоточности по умолчанию, с возможностью подкючить многопоточность.