# Как по очередно выполнять потоки не мешая основному потому в android

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь много файлов загрузить в googleDrive, загружать можно поочереди, когда загружаю не используя потоки, UI зависает если использую thread.join основной поток все равно останавливается и UI не работает, что можно сделать в моем случае, сейчас он пытается загрузить все сто фоток одновременно, а надо поочередно но не задевая основной поток.

```
public void createFiles() {
    File folderPhoto = new File(mSettings.getString(Const.directory, "") + "/");
    String[]  files = folderPhoto.list();
    for (String fileName : files) {

        File file1 = new File(mSettings.getString(Const.directory, "") + "/" + fileName);

        if (file1.isDirectory() || fileName.startsWith("."))
            continue;
        if(fileInFolders.contains(fileName))
            continue;
        createFile(file1, stringFolderId);
    }
}

public  void createFile(final File file, final String stringFrolderId) {

    final ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult> fileCallback1 = new
            ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFileResult result) {

                }
            };
    final  ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>  callbaCreatinFile   = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                return;
            }

            final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    OutputStream outputStream = null;
                    try {
........................
                        try {
                            outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            log(e1 + "");
                        }
                        MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder().setMimeType("image/jpeg").setTitle(file.getName()).build();
                        DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(mGoogleApiClient, DriveId.decodeFromString(stringFolderId));
                        folder.createFile(mGoogleApiClient, metadataChangeSet, driveContents).setResultCallback(fileCallback1);

                    }
                }
            };
            thread.start();
//               try {
//                thread.join();
  //          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //            e.printStackTrace();
      //      }
```

Comment: Смотрите этот ответ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424087/177345

Comment: Так же можете посмотреть в сторону сервисов - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: никогда не используйте thread.join()  в основном потоке.

Answer (score 1):

Есть класс `Executors` и его методы по созданию ExecutorService, которые могут начать выполнение одновременно, или по очереди. советую почитать.