# Вопрос о потоках в Java

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Например у меня есть такой код:

```
public static void getUser(int id) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            User user = API.getUser(id);
            ApplicationLoader.users.put(id, user);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

В другом потоке я например беру информацию из сети. 
После того как я получил информацию, поток сам закроется? Или он вообще закрываться не должен? Как все это дело работает?

А если например этот скрипт запустится сразу два раза? Например один из сервиса, а другой из активити.

Comment: Вот тут похожая тема, наверняка информация будет полезна вам. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424008/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-runnable-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2-java/424038#424038

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После выполнения последней строчки кода, все данные, ассоциированные с потоком, выгрузятся. Локальная память, занимаемая потоком, станет равна 0. И система уничтожит "мусорный" дескриптор. Так происходит в случае, когда код написан хорошо с учетом всех возможных ошибок и исключительных ситуаций.

Организовать многопоточность в Java можно не одним единственным способом. Android же предоставляет еще и ряд классов-надстроек, связанных с параллельным программированием и контролем последовательных действий (класс AsyncTask, например)

Если вы получили в потоке какие-либо данные, определенно, их необходимо куда-то сохранить\передавать-на-пост-обработку. Это уже зависит от вашего второго потока, код которого не предоставлен.

Comment: Юзер просто добавляется в статическую переменную в класс ApplicationLoader который наследует Application. Вот сама переменная `private static volatile HashMap<Integer, User> users = new HashMap<>();` , доступ к ней есть из любого потока, по этому AsyncTask не использовал, потому что не нужно