# Много одинаковых потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность

При нажатии кнопки каждый раз должен останавливаться предыдущий поток и запускаться точно такой же новый.

Как можно при каждом нажатии создавать новый поток неограниченное количество раз?

Comment: Doraemon, если ответ вас удовлетворяет, пожалуйста, примите его (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагаю, что имеется в виду кнопка, которая работает в главном потоке, у неё один обработчик событий. Кнопка не создаётся динамически в новых потоках.

Если для создания потоков применяете обычный способ - запуск в новом `Thread (thread.start)` объекта, реализующего `Runnable` интерфейс:

```
     RunnableSample rs1 = new RunnableSample();
     Thread workThread = new Thread(rs1);/*поток*/
     workThread.start();
```

То в классе формы наряду с кнопкой можно создать поле для потока. В нём хранить объект Thread.

Постановка задачи странная - "прервать текущий поток и запустить такой же новый". В зависимости от того, что ожидается от "прервать" и от "такой же новый", подойдут разные варианты прерывания работы потока:

```
    /*0*/workThread.suspend();/*+*/workThread.resume();
    /*1*/workThread.join(timeout);workThread.stop();/*+*/workThread.start();
    /*2*/workThread.stop();/*+*/workThread.start();
    /*3*/workThread.destroy();/*+*/workThread = new Thread(...); workThread.start();
```

Comment: `То в классе формы наряду с кнопкой можно создать поле для потока. В нём хранить объект Thread.` - можно поподробнее?)

Требуется безопасно прервать поток, после чего меняется одна из переменных, а затем запускается поток, исполняющий код предыдущего потока. Т.к. конкретный поток можно запустить только один раз, требуется, как я понимаю, каждый раз создавать поток с новым именем, но тем же кодом.

Comment: Переменную, которую предполагаете менять, поместите в класс, реализующий Runnable-интерфейс. Допустим, этот класс назовёте `RunnableSample`. Тогда в классе формы можно создать два поля `RunnableSample runnableSample;` и `Thread workThread;`. В конструкторе проинициализироать поля. В событии старта задать начальное значение переменной `runnableSample.param = 555` и стартануть поток `workThread.start();`. А в обработчике события нажатия кнопки: приостановить поток, изменить переменную `runnableSample.param` и продолжить работу потока. В этом случае пересоздавать объекты не понадобится.

Comment: Да, так будет проще. Спасибо.
А все же, для справки, каким способом можно было бы создать неограниченной количество потоков, как я описал ранее?

Comment: И оффтоповый вопрос: как приостановить поток на неограниченное время? Thread.sleep() требует интервал.

Comment: Thread.start() много раз. Если точно отвечать на вопрос, то я не знаю ответа на вопрос о неограниченном количестве. Каждый новый поток - это дескриптор, новая сущность. А количество дескрипторов ограничено операционной системой, поэтому, создать очень много потоков просто не удастся. Во всяком случае, в Windows. Также не удастся и организовать запуск огромного количества параллельных потоков, не хватит оперативной памяти и мощности процессора. Лучшая рекомендация - количество потоков равняется количеству ядер процессора, если ядер четыре, то четыре потока в самый раз.

Comment: Thread.suspend() приостановит поток. Thread.resume() возобновит работу потока.

Comment: Thread.suspend() объявлен Deprecated. Какие используются наиболее оптимальные способы?

Comment: Никогда. Слышите, НИКОГДА, не используйте Thread.stop(), Thread.suspend() и Thread.resume(). Эти методы давно считаются устравшими и их вызов может привести к неконсистентному состоянию программы и данных.

Comment: Утверждение о том, что количество потоков = кол-во ядер процессора - оптимально, тоже весьма сомнительного качества. В реальных системах потоков может быть сотни и все это нормально работает.

Comment: @zzashpaupat Как можно приостановить поток на неограниченное время, чтобы затем его возобновить?

Comment: @Doraemon разрулите это руками через wait()/notify()

Comment: @zzashpaupat хотелось бы пример, как это можно использовать для моей задачи

Answer (score 2):

Ваш вопрос разбивается на несколько:

**Как делать что-то по нажатию кнопки?**

Обычно кнопка реализует паттерн Observable, и на ее событие `onclick` подписывается Observer, в котором и выполняется нужный код. Детали зависят от конкретных используемых классов.

**Как *создавать* новый поток неограниченное количество раз?**

Оператором `new`

**Как этот поток потом запускать?**

- `Thread.run()`
- `Thread.run(Runnable r)`
- [использовать Executor Service](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424038/181472).

**Как останавливать поток?**

Отличный способ — [через reentrant lock](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436680/181472).

**Как это можно использовать для моей задачи**

Для начала, нужно чтобы вы описали вашу задачу максимально подробно, а также привели тот код, который вы УЖЕ написали для ее решения (и остановились на том месте, где что-то не понимаете).

Так уж тут принято. Пока нет постановки задачи, совершенно невозможно угадать, что именно будет для нее подходить.

- [Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
- [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)