# Приостановка потока на неограниченное время

Tags: java, многопоточность

Как наиболее оптимально из главного потока приостановить дочерний поток (Thread и Runnable) на неограниченное время, а затем его возобновить?

Comment: Doraemon, если ответ вас удовлетворяет, пожалуйста, примите его (галочка рядом с ответом)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не пользуйтесь методами `Thread.suspend()` и `Thread.resume()`.
Это лучше осуществить с помощью `wait()`/`notify()`.

Comment: можно пример кода?

Comment: @Doraemon, [вот](http://www.skipy.ru/technics/synchronization.html), [вот](http://initialize.ru/vzaimodeistvie-mejdu-potikami-java) и ещё [статья на Хабре по теме](http://habrahabr.ru/post/164487/)

Answer (score 3):

**Обновление**

Вы не можете «приостановить» чужой поток. Потоки должны сотрудничать для этого. Самый простой метод, наверное — использовать обыкновенный `Lock`.

Вот [пример](http://ideone.com/3wHoeD):

```
import java.time.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

class Test
{
    static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Thread worker = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                        // если lock взят, мы будет ждать здесь
                        // если нет, мы его берём и тут же отпускаем
                        lock.lock();
                        lock.unlock();
                        System.out.println(LocalTime.now());
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
            });
        worker.start();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println("Locking...");
        lock.lock();
        // теперь lock.lock() в другом потоке будет ждать
        Thread.sleep(500);
        lock.unlock();
        // в теперь не будет
        System.out.println("Unlocked");
        worker.join();
    }
}
```

Пару из `lock.lock(); lock.unlock();` нужно расставить по тем местам, где рабочий поток должен будет проверять, не нужно ли приостановиться. Это и есть «сотрудничество» — поток сам вызывает возможно блокирующий код в тех местах, где он хочет проверить, не нужно ли ему приостановиться.

Comment: можно так же пример, для решения конкретной задачи?

Comment: @Doraemon: так и у вас нет описания конкретной задачи.